# Running spring program inside application server

Tags: spring

I have here a slight problem.

We have written a big spring based application that runs on pure J2SE. No security manager, everything fine.

Now I got a request to get this app inside some container inside an application server. Obviously the application wont run after i am done with the porting because they have a security manger inside the server. Every call to reflection goes through it.

Have you any idea what can i do actually to make these two things work together.

Thanks

Comment: We do the same thing, use reflection and don't have issues with a security manager. I take it there is a security manager setup in the application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to configure the security manager to allow the reflective method calls to go through. You'll need to find the id of that permission and give permission for that call to happen.